# Writing JSON to a CSV column adds extra double quotations

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file like this:

```py
company, personnel
A company name,'[{"name": "Amir", "age": 24}, {"name": "Ali", "age": 34}, {"name": "Neda", "age": 25}]'
```

What I do is this:

```py
import json
import csv

f = open("companies.csv", 'w', buffering=1)
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(["company", "personnel"])

personnel = []
personnel.append({"name": "Amir", "age": 24})
personnel.append({"name": "Ali", "age": 34})
personnel.append({"name": "Neda", "age": 25})

writer.writerow(["A company name", json.dumps(personnel, ensure_ascii=False)])
f.close()
```

But the result is this:

```py
company,personnel
A company name,"[{""name"": ""Amir"", ""age"": 24}, {""name"": ""Ali"", ""age"": 34}, {""name"": ""Neda"", ""age"": 25}]"
```

As you can see, there are extra double quotation marks around each string. How can I fix this?

Comment: `writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'", delimiter=";")`

Comment: I'd recommend you to use 2 columns *(name, age)* and save values instead of dumping json into a single column. There's [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), you can use it.